# What is the fastest way of finding a complement?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am given a direct factor $N$ which is a normal subgroup of a group $G$. I want to find a [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(group_theory)) of $N$ in $G$. The model of computation is RAM. It takes $O(n)$ time to find an inverse of one element. It takes $O(1)$ time to do the operation $a.b$, where $.$ means group operation. The size of the group is $n$ and group is given by table representation.

I tried to search on Google but did not able to find any algorithm for the above problem.

> **Q.** What is the most efficient algorithm to find a complement of a direct factor?

Comment: This can be done in polynomial time. The complement you are looking for is also a complement of $Z(G)=Z(N)$ in $C_G(N)$, so you can first reduce to the case when $N \le Z(G)$ by computing $C_G(N)$ and $Z(G)$. Since the group is given by its multiplication table, you can do that by brute force. Then finding a complement becomes a cohomological calculation. This is described for example in 7.6.2 of "Handbook of Computational Group Theory" by Holt. Eick and O'Brien. I think it is essentially the same calculation as that described in the paper cited by Francesco Polizzi.

Comment: By the way, as I think I said in a comment to one of your other posts, multiplication table is really not a sensible way to input a group, and none of the literature on computational group theory that I am aware of uses that as a model. Permutation or matrix representations, together with power-conjugate presentations for polycyclic groups, are the models used in practice, both in theoretical work and in implementations. Groups are always input by means of generating sets rather than elementwise.

Comment: Not that it makes much difference, but if the group has order $n$, and multiplication takes $O(1)$ time, you can compute the inverse $a^{-1}=a^{n-1}$ in time $O(\log n)$ (rather than $O(n)$) by repeated squaring.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is solvable, an algorithm that returns a set of representatives for the conjugacy classes of complements of a normal subgroup $N$ in $G$ is implemented in the Computer Algebra Software [GAP4](https://www.gap-system.org/).

See [Chapter 39](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html) of GAP4 documentation, in particular Section 39.11-6. The example given there is the following:

```
gap> g:=Group((1,2,3,4),(1,2));;
gap> ComplementClassesRepresentatives(g,Group((1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)));
[ Group([ (3,4), (2,4,3) ]) ]
```

The algorithm is based on the paper

F. Celler, J. Neubüser, C. R. B. Wright: [*Some remarks on the computation of complements and normalizers in soluble groups*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00053292), Acta Appl. Math. **21**, No.1-2, 57-76 (1990). [ZBL0719.20010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0719.20010).

Comment: @ Francesco Polizzi  Thanks for the answer. I am looking for the algorithm. I mean some algorithm with polynomial running time.

Comment: GAP uses an algorithm developed by Celler et al. I will add the reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a polynomial time algorithm to find complement of a subgroup of given group by Cayley table representation. Please refer [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/groupFactoring.pdf) paper by Neeraj Kaya and Timur Nezhmetdinov.

Also there is a stronger result by James B. Wilson, which gives a polynomial time algorithm for computing complement when the group is given by permutation representation. Refer [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0548.pdf) link for the same.

Comment: Your first reference only seems to be for finding complements which give rise to direct product decompositions, not complements (unless I am missing some lemma which is more general).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Well that is the case the OP asks for, at least.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The answer finds a normal complement, but OP just asks for a complement. I see no reason to expect that an algorithm for finding normal complements should be the most efficient for finding complements (even assuming a normal complement exists).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Good point.  The diagonal subgroup of $G\times G$ is an easy example of a non-normal complement to the obvious direct factors.

Comment: I am confused with complement and a normal complement. Also, @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda how your example is counter one ?